# Using XPath with GPathResult to find all nodes and add new attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, groovy, xmlslurper, gpath

Edited...
My knowledge in Groovy is basic and I need to perform the following action which I have no idea how to do.

let's say I have this XML:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
  <ns2:analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse>
      <ns2:productOfferings>
        <ns2:productOffering xsi:type="ns2:ProductOfferingInstanceCore" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
           <ns2:opExtn>C_P87531945-0993-46d1-8f23-ed23caa6e0cf</ns2:opExtn>
           <ns2:productOffering>
              <ns9:id>8447669</ns9:id>
           </ns2:productOffering>
           <ns2:productOffering>
              <ns9:id>8447100</ns9:id>
           </ns2:productOffering>
        </ns2:productOffering>
     </ns2:productOfferings>
  </ns2:analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

given an XPath expression like:

```
/Body/analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse/productOfferings/productOffering/productOffering
```

and GPathResult as:

```
gpathRequest = new XmlSlurper().parse(inputFile)
```

I know how to use findAll to search for all related tags. Let's say I stored the Xpath in a xPath variable:

```
def gpath = "XML." + xPaths
child = Eval.me( 'XML', gpathRequest, gpath ).depthFirst().findAll{it.value}
```

However I am not sure how to handle the result here in form of collection. How can I add a new property after finding the result I need?

Comment: Can you come up with an example that makes sense?

Comment: Sorry, I am having problem phrasing what I need. Updated the question on what I reached so far. However I am not sure even this can have any Xpath expression.. I tried and it failed with something like: "//*[@attr=="id"]. So my question is actually twofold - 1. can I use any Xpath expression. 2. how do use the result to add new property to productOffering node.

Comment: @YossiEven, can you please check the below solution to see if that helps?

Comment: I doubt you can navigate a GPathResult with an XPath query?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of new product offerings and loop thru the list to add new `productOffering` nodes.

Do not need to use `xpath`. Instead find parent node which `productOfferings` and `appendNode` be used to achieve the same.

*See the below script:*

```
def newOfferings = [8447101, 8447102]

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(inputFile)

def offerings = xml.'**'.find{it.name() == 'productOfferings'}

newOfferings.each { val ->
   offerings.appendNode {
       'ns2.productOffering' {
          'ns9.id'(val)
       }
   }
}
```

You can quick try the same online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/UTlZzW)</kbd>

Comment: Thing is the Xpath is given by outside source (configuration) so I don't know what is the actual path I am looking for. This is why I am using it as input on the eval. doing it like you did means I know how the XML And the Path will look like, which I cannot assume to know. I want to be able to dynamically extract the nodes I need and add my attribute